# How to make Python see module installed via apt?

Tags: python, travis-ci, dbus

I'm trying to use Travis CI to run tests of my Python code.

My project needs dbus module and it's not available in PyPi, so I have to install it via apt.

Problem is that tests fail with ImportError: No module named 'dbus'. It's quite strange, because I can see in report about successful installation of required packages. Here is my [.travis.yml](https://github.com/valericus/balooner/blob/development/.travis.yml) and example of [Travis log](https://travis-ci.org/valericus/balooner/jobs/84862740).

Do I do something wrong?

Comment: This is interesting. You know what I am suspecting? It is only a suspicion. Travis is setting up a virtualenv and your apt-get is installing outside the virtualenv. So it will never see your package.

Comment: But. I'm sure there is a solution to this if that is the case. I use Travis. Let me see something. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the travis log you posted, all your packages are being installed in a virtual environment.

The virtual environment is created in a clean state - so it does not have any links to system libraries, indeed it states so in the [documentation](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/#Travis-CI-Uses-Isolated-virtualenvs):

> CI Environment uses separate virtualenv instances for each Python
>   version. System Python is not used and should not be relied on. If you
>   need to install Python packages, do it via pip and not apt.
>
> If you decide to use apt anyway, note that Python system packages only
>   include Python 2.7 libraries on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. This means that the
>   packages installed from the repositories are not available in other
>   virtualenvs even if you use the –system-site-packages option.

I believe it explains your problem:

1. virtual environments are isolated and have no link to system packages.
2. Even if you use apt, it is **limited to Python 2.7**, and you are trying to install a `python3-` package.